# Unable to call the declared prototype on Number while String works in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, prototype

I've declared two methods.

```
String.prototype.hazaa = function (shazoo) {
  return this + shazoo;
}

Number.prototype.hazaa = function (shazoo) {
  return this + shazoo;
}
```

When I call the former, I get the expected behavior. However, invoking the second one, produces the error below.

> Syntax error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL(...)

I have the feeling that it's my C#-ishness that is spooking (I'm thinking extension methods and object oriented calls). The invocation's performed as follows.

```
"abc".hazaa("shazoo");
12345.hazaa(00000000);
```

Is there another syntax to invoke the function I've added? Have I not declared the prototype addition the right way?

Yes, I have made [the research](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_num.asp) but I might be missing a relevant point.

Comment: in javascript, if you want to access a property of a number literal that is an integer ... `12345..hazaa(000000)` ... double dot for the win ... it's a brave man that links to w3schools with the words `the research` ... the second time I did that on SO was the last - people get so upset :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Hehehe. I realize that my sarcasm doesn't show. Perhaps I should rephrase to "*excelled formidably at the research at the ultimate source of wisdom*", hihi.

Comment: _"I might be missing a relevant point"_ turns out it was the _decimal_ point :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe That's golden! I'm going to tell my team that they're *missing **the** point*, when they remark or nag about the "typo", hahaha. I'll take the liberty to update your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is while it is parsing `12345.hazaa(00000000);`, it sees `hazaa` as coming after the decimal point in the number, hence the unexpected token.  If you wrap the number in parentheses it is parsed and executed correctly:

```
(12345).hazaa(00000000);
```

It will continue to work normally on variables, as the parsing has already happened:

```
var a = 123;
a.hazaa(0000);
```

As mentioned by Jaromanda X in the comments, another alternative to allow correct parsing is to use a double-dot syntax:

```
12345..hazaa(00000000);
```

Comment: or what I said `12345..hazaa(00000000);` ... I'll let you use it in your answer as a sexy alternative - it saves a **whole** byte :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh nice, haven't seen that used before.  I'm not sure which I prefer!

Comment: @JaromandaX I get the syntax (my ignorance was the root cause of the error, of course). I can't wait to show the syntaxes to my team. They'll gonna correct it for sure! Parentheses appear to be superfluous and double-dotting looks like a darn typo. I'm so happy right now. LOS...

Comment: @KonradViltersten I appreciate the edit for amusement value, but if/when the comments get cleared up, without that context of that chatter it made my answer seem to start off a bit rude :)

Comment: Your answer - your call. Just for the records, I wouldn't find that a bit rude. More entertainingly informative. But I'm known to be a bit buffalo with skin hard as rhino's butt, so my measure is likely to be wrong. Feel free to remove your and mine comment when you've seen it.